# Nginx configuration to handle two SPA

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two different SPA (serving by two node server on different ports) behind Nginx reverse proxy. The problem is that both apps serve their static files from /static/files/
How can I config Nginx to serve the files from the right node server without changing the static folder name?

Comment: 1st Approach - Set a cookie value from backend and based on that value redirect to respective node server. 2nd Approach - add an `path_variable` in the url itself and decide based on that. Like `https://example.com/nodejs1/` and `https://example.com/nodejs2/`

Comment: The 1st approach seems good, but what if a user opens two tabs from each server? The cookie will override by one of the tabs and the solution won't work.

Comment: Well in that case you have to go with the 2nd approach and set the path of static files during build process. `nodejs1/static/files/` and `nodejs2/static/files/`. Did you use module bundler ( webpack etc ) for manage client side.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. But I want to handle it without any change in Webpack building configuration. It is against "Convention over configuration" concept that 'CreateReactApp' is based on it. (I use ReactJs based on CreateReactApp)